# How am I supposed to add Jooq Express via maven?

Tags: jooq

I just bought JOOQ Express.  I can see where I can download a .zip file containing a bunch of .jar files but I used maven for my build.  I also github actions running builds which normally download everything from maven.

Do I have to dump all of these files into my source repo/git?  Or can I somehow reference my JOOQ express via some maven repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of jOOQ 3.17, there are 2 main options:

1. You set up an artifact repository and deploy the jar files in there, and make it available to your github actions
2. You check in the jar files in some source repository (the same one or a different one if you prefer not having too many large files in your main repository)

There's a pending feature request to offer a public repository for commercial jOOQ artifacts: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9906. Alternatively, these might be published to Maven Central, as various vendors have started doing (e.g. for JDBC drivers, etc.), despite the artifacts not being open source.